# How do we need to apply Chebyshev's and Markov's inequality here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb R$ with $$\int_{(-1,\:1)}\nu({\rm d}x)x^2<\infty\tag1$$ and $\nu(\{0\})=0$, $$I_k:=\left(-\frac1k,-\frac1{k+1}\right]\cup\left[\frac1k,\frac1{k+1}\right)$$ and $$\nu_k(B):=\nu(B\cap I_k)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$$ for $k\in\mathbb N$ and $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a real-valued independent process on some probability space with $$\operatorname E[X_k]=\int\nu_k({\rm d}x)x=\int_{I_k}\nu({\rm d}x)x\tag2$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X_k]=\int\nu_k({\rm d}x)x^2=\int_{I_k}\nu({\rm d}x^2)\tag3$$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and $$M_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(X_i-\operatorname E[X_i]\right)\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N.$$

It's easy to see that $M$ is a martingale with $$\operatorname E\left[M_k^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^k\operatorname{Var}[X_i]\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N\tag4$$ and hence $$\sup_{kn\in\mathbb N}\operatorname E\left[M_k^2\right]=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\operatorname{Var}[X_k]=\int_{(-1,\:1)}\nu({\rm d}x)x^2<\infty\tag5.$$

Now let $b\in\mathbb R$, $\sigma\ge0$, $b^{(n)}:=b/n$, $\sigma^{(n)}:=\sigma/\sqrt n$, $\nu^{(n)}:=\nu/n$ and define $(X^{(n)}_k,M^{(n)}_k)$ as above, but with $\nu$ replaced by $\nu^{(n)}$, for $n\in\mathbb N$. Finally, let $Z$ be a standard normally distributed random variable independent of $X^{(n)}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

> Given $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$, how can we show that there are $k_0,n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $$\operatorname P\left[\left|b^{(n)}+\sigma^{(n)}Z+\sum_{k>k_0}\left(X_k^{(n)}-\operatorname E\left[X_k^{(n)}\right]\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\operatorname E\left[X^{(n)}_k\right]\right|\ge\varepsilon_1\right]\le\frac{\varepsilon_2}n\tag6$$ for all $n\ge n_0$?

We may clearly use the triangle inequality to write the probability on the left-hand side as a sum of four parts. We may choose $n_0\in\mathbb N$ large enough to ensure $\left|b^{(n)}\right|<\varepsilon_1/4$ for all $n\ge n_0$. By Markov's inequality, $$\operatorname P\left[\left|\sigma^{(n)}Z\right|\ge\frac{\varepsilon_1}4\right]\le\frac{48}{n^2}\left(\frac\sigma{\varepsilon_1}\right)^4\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag7.$$ Moreover, $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\operatorname E\left[X_k^{(n)}\right]\right|\le\frac1n\int_{\left(-1,\:-\frac1{k_0+1}\right]\:\cup\:\left[\frac1{k_0+1},\:1\right)}\nu({\rm d}x)|x|\tag8$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. And using Chebyshev's inequality, we obtain $$\operatorname P\left[\left|\sum_{k>k_0}\left(X_k^{(n)}-\operatorname E\left[X_k^{(n)}\right]\right)\right|\ge\frac{\varepsilon_1}4\right]\le\left(\frac4{\varepsilon_1}\right)^2\frac1n\int_{\left(-\frac1{k_0+1},\:\frac1{k_0+1}\right)}\nu({\rm d}x)x^2\tag9$$ for all $k_0,n\in\mathbb N$.

> How do we need to deal with $(8)$ and $(9)$ to find suitable choices for $k_0,n_0$?

Comment: How do you get (8) from (2)? If (2) holds with $\nu$ replaced by $\frac{\nu}{n}$, then there should be no $|x|$ in (8), I think.

Comment: @saz There was an "$x$" missing in the integrand on the rhs of $(2)$. Does that answer your question?